# Filter data by year w/o changes to SOQL?

Tags: apex, filters

Trying to filter data that is returned to me by the termination year. If any data that is pulled and has a termination date older then five years I do not want it to show up.

```
public static List<date> filter(List<date> results) {
    List<date> filtered = new List<date>();
    Date t = Date.today();
    for (date r : results) {
        Date d = r.lastModifiedDate;
        if (date == 'year') {
            if (d > t.addYears(-5)) {
                filtered.add(r);
            }
        } else {
            // Add all to the list if no filter selected
            filtered.add(r);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

I'm receiving two errors right now.

"Variable does not exist: lastModifiedDate"
"Variable does not exist: date"

Comment: `results` list is of type `date` , and Date object does not contain `lastModifiedDate`

Comment: @Gevin for which object you are trying to do this?

Comment: the object I am trying to pull this data from is called TerminationDate__c

Comment: I think that showing us some details about how this `filter()` method is being called (and how you're getting the data you're passing into it) would help. The documentation on [SOQL Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) will probably help you here (and you could probably use the undocumented `N_YEARS_AGO:n` literal).